# graph aggregation on mongoldb - limit document size

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with thousands of documents. Documents are like this:

```
{ "username" : "username_A","user_id" : "797684007", "follower_list_user_id" :[ "646923768", "1366379506", "1511259832"] }
```

I want to find a path (nodes) that show how can reach username A from other user_ids(or usernames),(actually, search in "follower_list_user_id" and find the path.) 
I was writing this $graphLookup aggregation:

```
db.testDB.aggregate({$match:{ "username": "username_A" } },{ $graphLookup: {from: "testDB", startWith: "$follower_list_user_id", connectFromField: "user_id", connectToField: "follower_list_user_id"  as: "results" , depthField: 'steps'}} )
```

But I got MongoDB error about document size limit. result document was more than 16 MB. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202683/mongodb-document-size-of-29344731-is-larger-than-maximum-of-16777216  this might help

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to get. Could you add an example of the kind of info or document you wish to get out of your query?

Comment: @mig I want to find a graph of relations between username( or user_id). for example user A have user_id:103 and follower_list_user_id:[123,302], user B have user_id:302 and follower_list_user_id:[123,43224] , user C have user_id:532 and follower_list_user_id :[9923,433], etc. I want to find nodes( path ) of relations of "user_id"s! in this example, find that I can reach user B from user A.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-use-aggregation-for-large-collection/121749